# On click goes to next page - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello I have one confusion in my head. 
I'm trying to make a logic in JS when some one click on BUTTON then automatically lead to next page after 1s. 
I tried to use onclick function but I'm getting error. 
I included simple html and css in purpose of texting. 
Can some one help me.
Also That logic must apply to any pages.

Cheers!

```css
#btn {
    position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 80px;
 content: 'Button';
 background: blue;
  border-radius: 9px;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#next {
    position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 80px;
 content: 'Button';
 background: blue;
  border-radius: 9px;
  color: white;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#text {
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;

  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>!!!AAA!!!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="btn"><div id="text">Button</div></div>
 <div id="next"><div id="text">next</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your JS code so we can help you. And what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go to a different page after 1 second you'll want to use a combination of `setTimeout()` and `window.location` and an `onclick` event on your button.

I am assuming you want to use the button next to make this happen.

First thing create a second html test page.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

and in the code you shared, after the closing `</div>` tag for id next add the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>!!!AAA!!!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="btn">
    <div id="text">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div id="nextPage">
    <button id="next" onclick="switchLocation(0)">next</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function switchLocation(counter) {
      if (counter == 0) {
        counter = 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
          switchLocation(counter);
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        window.location = "page2.html";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I edited your code slightly. Removed the extra `<` on the first line and changed the "next" div to a button.

Comment: You should at least post valid HTML `<button id="next" onclick="switchLocation(0)">next</div>`