# Random Image Generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm not sure how to approach something like this and I have looked around just not found what I'm after.

I would like to be able to state the amount of images at the top of (lets say) a script file and list the image names. The script would then see the amount of images and see the list and then randomly generate a number picking that image that represents that number. The image would then be displayed on the website.

I'm certain this can be done with JavaScript, I'm just not sure how. Feel free to make changes to my plan as I'm new to JavaScript so not sure on how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: I would highly recommend doing some tutorials on Javascript before asking such a question. What you're asking can be accomplished with a trivial knowledge of JS.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials you can recommend? Any Youtuber in specific or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript I would use an array of image file names, use a math.random function, and assign that array index to the img id in the html.

I have written something that you can test below. You'll have to use your own fileNames and filepath, but once you have that setup, refresh your testpage and verify that random images get displayed.

```html
<html>

<body onload="randomImage()">

  <img id="yourImageID" src="" alt="random image">

  <script>
    function randomImage() {
      //Array of filenames
      var fileNames = [
        "dog.png",
        "cat.png",
        "cow.png"
      ];

      //get a random index for the array
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileNames.length);

      //assign that value to your img tag
      document.getElementById("yourImageID").src = "filepath/" + fileNames[randomIndex];
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What would I add to make the image change after a set time rather than having the refresh the page?

Comment: You would want to use setTimeout(). [Here is an older post that might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524715/on-click-goes-to-next-page-javascript/35525051#35525051)